# How to retrieve the difference of time value based on key from Data frame in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame stored in a variable `testResult` which consist of time and customer id as seen below:

```
Time of Transaction | Customer-ID
            1:02:10 |         101
            4:02:10 |         101
            6:02:10 |         101
            9:02:10 |         109
            9:05:10 |         109
```

As per above table, I'm trying to find the difference betwwen the transaction times done by each customer. I have a generic method that would retrieve the difference of subsequent number and I would like to use it for retrieving the time difference as seen below:

```
var get_time_for_User=testResult.rdd.map(r => (r(0), r(1))).groupByKey().map(rec => rec._1, getResult(rec._2))

def getResult(list: List[Int]): Array[Int] = {
  val result= list.sliding(2).map(r => r(1) - r(0)) .toArray
  return result
}
```

I'm not sure this would be the correct way as `getResult` should take the timestamp and find the difference of the same from `get_time_for_User`.

The expected output is:

```
101: 3, 2
109: 3
```

Would be appreciated if anyone can help on this.

Comment: I do not think that `groupByKey` guarantees the order of "grouped" elements. Do all these "time" entries belong to the same day? Are you only interested in "hours" of difference. Why do you not think this would be the correct way?

Comment: Is there a date associated with the time? Is there a date column?

Comment: read about window functions, I think you can calculate the difference between 2 consecutive rows using it: 
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

Comment: Hi @Sarvesh Kumar Singh and Taha Naqvi  . the time value contains only the time,  not the date. The time coloum is associated with the respective date and that is in different coloum.